# Why can't I use an alias used in a subquery in a where clause in a select clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql

For example, there is below.

```
SELECT cost, min_cost 
FROM item WHERE item.cost > (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM item) AS min_cost;
```

What was wrong with this?

I'm curious what's wrong with grammar.

Alias can't allowed at where clause?

Comment: What kind of an answer would you like? All code has rules, so when those rules aren't followed, the code parser complains.

Comment: @Strawberry I want to know if there are any rules related to why the above code is not running.

Comment: You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Comment: You can select values only from those tables and subqueries which are listed in the FROM clause. If you want to select the `min_cost` - you will have to move the subquery to the FROM clause.

Comment: The rules can be found in the manual for example 'SELECT is used to retrieve rows selected from one or more tables, and can include UNION statements and subqueries'  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html , 'Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the reply. However, in this case, unlike the content mentioned, the select clause refers to the alias of the where clause.

Comment: And  does not come into the rule''SELECT is used to retrieve rows selected FROM one or more tables, and can include UNION statements and subqueries'  - A subquery in a where is not available and syntactically invalid and even if it was what you have is a table alias not a column alias. You should also read up sql order of execution - which says that FROM (including joins,unions etc) is executed before WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use alias name in a where clause. Note that you are using alias in where clause not inside the subquery.

This is the way you should modify the query to get the desired results :

```
select cost ,  min(cost) as min_cost 
from item where item.cost > min_cost group by <some-column>;
```

This query will return all the costs(grouped by that particular column) that are greater than the minimum cost.

Comment: 'Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.' - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html - and even if it did an aggregate function without a group by will return only 1 row

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had just forgotten this. And I have made the necessary edits to the post

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question